# how to use high chart when number of lines are dynamic

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I need to show some numbers for different entities like person 1 and 2 and ... in multi line graph:

After searching a lot I found high chart better and I designed something like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

series: [{
    color:'red',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
},{
    color:'blue',
    data: [19.9, 11.5, 10.4, 12.2, 14.0, 16.0, 13.6, 18.5, 16.4, 94.1, 9.6, 4.4]
}]

});
```

and here is the fiddle link:

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/bdRPL/1/)

Now the problem is I do not know how many entities the user choose for showing in the graph,
it may be 2 entities(lines) or 3 or 4 or whatever. In the code that I provided it is not dynamic and if I want to make it work for 3 lines or 4 lines then I have to hard code it with different functions which does not make sense. Does anyone have any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But You can do it like this

```
var seriesOne={color:'red',
               data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
},
    seriesTwo= {color:'blue',
                data: [19.9, 11.5, 10.4, 12.2, 14.0, 16.0, 13.6, 18.5, 16.4, 94.1, 9.6, 4.4]
},
   //---
seriesN= {color:'red',
          data: [ 14.0, 16.0, 13.6,94.1, 9.6, 4.4, 19.9, 11.5, 10.4, 12.2,18.5, 16.4, ]
},
   youDynamicSeries = [];

   youDynamicSeries.push(seriesOne);
   youDynamicSeries.push(seriesTwo);
   youDynamicSeries.push(seriesN);


$('#container').highcharts({

xAxis: {
     categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

series: youDynamicSeries

 });
```

Comment: Yes You are awesome:)